# Jenkins - trigger build only for new release branches

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-2

I have some old release branches in git: **release/2022.1, release/2022.2, release/2022.3**.. I have some old ones for the previous years as well.
Now starting from branch **release/2022.4** and for the following years from now on, I would like to trigger my Jenkins build job when that branch is created from master (it will not be modified).
The issue: when I do the configuration of the Jenkins it automatically triggers job for all my **previous** release branches which is NOT what I want. How to tell Jenkins **"start from now on"** for every new **release** branch?

Configuration:

```
Discover branches:
Exclude branches that are also filed as PRs

Discover pull requests from origin:
Merging the pull request with the current target branch revision

Filter by name (with wildcards):
Include:
release/*
```

Thanks a lot!!!